# What data type would the variable in "TEXTFILE = open('x.txt','a')" be?

Tags: python, types

When testing python describes it as "_io.TextIOWrapper", I am not too sure  what data type this is.

Comment: open() returns a file object. See the documentation here for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: It's exactly what it [says it is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Comment: @JacobH Not in Python 3 (or rather, there is a wider range of objects returned by `open`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2:

```
>>> f = open("junk.txt", "a")
>>> f
<open file 'junk.txt', mode 'a' at 0xb72ddee8>
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
>>>
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> f = open("junk.txt", "a")
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='junk.txt' mode='a' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, it can come in handy :)